# We are facing Nodejs response time issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nginx

We are facing Nodejs response time issue when we reach about 100 online users our response time gets to 10s. I think there is a messy code that makes my app work slow. Is there any way to trace down the issue (on witch code my app becomes slow) on my nodejs application ? Im using nodejs, expressjs, mongodb and nginx

NGINX:

```
upstream http_backend {
   server 127.0.0.1:8087;
   keepalive 32;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  cdn.amjilt.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 7070;
    listen [::]:7070;
    server_name  cdn.amjilt.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name  cdn.amjilt.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert/media/media.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert/media/media.key;

    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    client_max_body_size 500M;
    client_body_buffer_size 500M;
    proxy_buffer_size   16M;
    proxy_buffers   24 8M;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    location /images{
            root /home/ubuntu/projects/amjilt_media/static;
    }
    location /tmp{
            root /home/ubuntu/projects/amjilt_media/static;
    }
    location /images/uploads{
            root /home/ubuntu/projects/amjilt_media/static;
    }
    location /images/avatar{
            root /home/ubuntu/projects/amjilt_media/static;
    }
    location /api/video/show{
            expires off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            chunked_transfer_encoding on;
            proxy_pass http://http_backend;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }
    location /api/video/mobile{
            expires off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            chunked_transfer_encoding on;
            proxy_pass http://http_backend;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }
    location /api/pdf/show{
            expires off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            chunked_transfer_encoding on;
            proxy_pass http://http_backend;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8087;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    # gzip
    gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
    gzip on;
}
```

ROUTER:

```
let flname = '../../..' + video.path;
var file = path.resolve(__dirname, flname);
fs.stat(file, function(err, stats) {
    if (err) {
        winston.error('/video/show/:id fs.stat error ',err);
        if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
            // 404 Error if file not found
            res.status(404).json({msg: 'log.n_request'});
        }
        res.status(404).json({msg: 'log.n_request'});
    }
    var range = req.headers.range;
    if (!range) {
        var stat_ = fs.statSync(file)
        var header = {
            'Content-Length': stat_.size,
            'Content-Type': (!req.useragent.isSafari ? token : 'mp4'),
        }
        res.writeHead(200, header)
        var stream = fs.createReadStream(file)
            .on("open", function () {
                stream.pipe(res);
            }).on("error", function (err) {
                res.end(err);
            });
    }else{
        var positions = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
        var start = parseInt(positions[0]);
        if(isNaN(start)){
            start = 0;
        }
        var total = stats.size;
        var end = positions[1] ? parseInt(positions[1]) : (start+102400);
        if(isNaN(end)){
            end = start+102400;
        }
        if(total <= end){
            end = total-1;
        }
        var chunksize = (end - start) + 1;

        res.writeHead(206, {
            "Content-Range": "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + total,
            "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
            "Content-Length": chunksize,
            "Content-Type": "video/mp4"
        });

        var stream = fs.createReadStream(file, {start: start, end: end})
            .on("open", function () {
                stream.pipe(res);
            }).on("error", function (err) {
                res.end(err);
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: Use `console.time` and `console.timeEnd` on different layers of your app and find out. There isn't any node specific way. Measure how long it takes for nodejs to retrieve data from mongo, how long it takes for the user to get a response from server, etc. Try each layer and find out what the bottleneck is.

Comment: One obvious thing to look for is if you have any synchronous I/O (particularly synchronous file system or child_process stuff).  That will block node.js so that it can only work on one request at a time.  If you can post code for specific requests that are having performance problems, we can look at it.  Other potential bottlenecks to add time logging to are places where you access the database.  If you have 100 online users all triggering a bunch of database requests, your database could be the bottleneck too.

Comment: @jfriend00 we let users to upload videos (multer) and let users to stream it using fs would that cause any issue ?

Comment: @Orgil - It depends upon how the code is written.  We'd have to see the actual code to advise.  If you're using any fs.*Sync methods, that would be bad.  If you're supporting streaming a lot of videos, you could be bandwidth limited too (depends upon your provider bandwidth, your network interface and some other network configuration things).  Hard drive speed could be relevant too.  What are the CPU and disk utilization at keeping mind that nodejs uses only one CPU for running your Javascript, but may use more than one for disk I/O?

Comment: @jfriend00 I have edited the question can take a look please ? :D  i have actually separated media server stream and uploading. but old videos are still streaming from the main server the main server has a 10 ghz 4 cores CPU, 16 gb memory, the new media server has 2ghz 2 cores 2x CPU, 24gb memory, 2tb hard

Comment: `fs.statSync()` is evil.  Replace it with `fs.stat()` and write asynchronous code.  But, I don't even understand why you're using it because you just did `fs.stat()` on the same file earlier in the same function.  I'll make some code suggestions in a moment.

Comment: 1. upstream prematurely closed connection while sending to client, 2. upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, 2. no live upstreams while connecting to upstream -> i get this errors sometimes in nginx log

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `fs.statSync()`.  That clogs up the event loop so your server gets stuck handling one request at a time every time you run that.  And, as it turns out, you can just remove the call entirely because you've already called `fs.stat()` on the same file earlier in the function and can just use those results.

I also added a couple return statements after sending errors since you don't want the rest of the code to execute after sending an error:

```
let flname = '../../..' + video.path;
var file = path.resolve(__dirname, flname);
fs.stat(file, function(err, stats) {
    if (err) {
        winston.error('/video/show/:id fs.stat error ',err);
        if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
            // 404 Error if file not found
            res.status(404).json({msg: 'log.n_request'});
            return;
        }
        res.status(404).json({msg: 'log.n_request'});
        return;
    }
    var range = req.headers.range;
    if (!range) {
        var header = {
            'Content-Length': stats.size,
            'Content-Type': (!req.useragent.isSafari ? token : 'mp4'),
        }
        res.writeHead(200, header)
        var stream = fs.createReadStream(file)
            .on("open", function () {
                stream.pipe(res);
            }).on("error", function (err) {
                res.end(err);
            });
    }else{
        var positions = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
        var start = parseInt(positions[0]);
        if(isNaN(start)){
            start = 0;
        }
        var total = stats.size;
        var end = positions[1] ? parseInt(positions[1]) : (start+102400);
        if(isNaN(end)){
            end = start+102400;
        }
        if(total <= end){
            end = total-1;
        }
        var chunksize = (end - start) + 1;

        res.writeHead(206, {
            "Content-Range": "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + total,
            "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
            "Content-Length": chunksize,
            "Content-Type": "video/mp4"
        });

        var stream = fs.createReadStream(file, {start: start, end: end})
            .on("open", function () {
                stream.pipe(res);
            }).on("error", function (err) {
                res.end(err);
            });
     }
});
```

Comment: does it affect cpu usage ? slow down entire node app ? if many users starts streaming

Comment: @Orgil - Synchronous file I/O clogs the event loop so your server gets stuck serving one user at a time rather than advancing many users at a time.  It just ruins scalability. It doesn't necessarily hog the CPU, it just stalls the event loop everytime you call `fs.statSync()`, nothing else can run while the interpreter is waiting for that to return.  If you use `fs.stat()` instead, then other requests can run while waiting for that to return.  This is a fundamental thing in node.js asynchronous design.

Comment: @Orgil - How many CPU cores in the server that you can use?  I asked because if you're doing lots of file I/O and have lots of cores, it might make sense to increase the file system thread pool size.  Internally, in native code the `fs` module uses a thread pool in libuv for the actual asynchronous file I/O.  That doesn't help if you're using synchronous file I/O, but might help once you get rid of blocking the event loop.  And, if you have any `fs.xxxxSync()` calls ANYWHERE else in your server, you need to systematically get rid of them all.

Comment: i have actually separated media server stream and uploading. but old videos are still streaming from the main server the main server has a 10 ghz 4 cores CPU, 16 gb memory, the new media server has (2ghz 2 cores) 2x CPU, 24gb memory, 2tb hard

Comment: and 1 more problem is im getting error in nginx log ( recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream )  on the video stream api url   its related to nginx and server config i think but cant resolve